# How to snap a window in Windows 10 1809 "Snip and Sketch" app?

Tags: windows-10

The Windows snipping tool supported the capture of a window frame by selecting the capture mode. How is this performed in the "Snip and Sketch" tool introduced in Windows 10 1809?

Comment: You don’t; it isn’t a feature of the application yet;

Comment: You may want to add tags [tag:snipping] and [tag:snipping-tool] to the question.

Comment: Currently it is able to capture a window! I think this is newly added to the application.